# Python-pptx fonts get reset to Arial on Google Drive

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, python-pptx, google-slides

When I use the python-pptx package to export a Presentation within a Google Colab/Drive environment, many of the fonts get reset to a default font (Arial).

I'm running this simple script to load in a .pptx file as a Presentation object and then export it to a .pptx file.  The expected outcome is that it will essentially copy the slide deck and rename it.  However, it is not retaining all of my font formattting, as can be seen in the attached image.

```
%pip install python-pptx
from pptx import Presentation

template = Presentation('/path_to_folder/Input.pptx')
template.save('/path_to_folder/Output.pptx')
```

This has been working as intended as recently as two weeks ago, so I'm not sure if it is the result of an update to python-pptx or Google Slides.

When I run the same script (minus the `%pip install` line) on my local machine, the fonts are retained and the output is generated as expected, with my original formatting intact.

[Image of font conversion issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1ZPu.png)

Comment: Where are you viewing the output PPTX file when the fonts are missing? In general, fonts used by PowerPoint reside on the machine opening the presentation and not within the presentation itself. The code you show is not touching fonts at all, so I'd look at differences in the machines you're rendering on.

Comment: The effect seems to be the same whether I open the PPTX file in Google Slides on Drive, or if I use Powerpoint on my local machine.

Comment: Check the original .pptx file for embedded fonts. It's possible that `python-pptx` strips those because they're outside the normal package or something. It's never come up before to my knowledge and I'm not sure how those are stored in a .pptx file. But if they're present before and absent after, that provides a clear line of inquiry.